# Assigning Intune scope tags to Azure Azure AD group

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-intune

I cannot figure this on out. I need a way to assign *Endpoint Manager's Scope tags to an Azure AD group* using **Microsoft Graph** and **PowerShell**.

Under the portal this is done under *Endpoint Manager\Tenant Administration\Roles\Scope (Tags)*. Then clicking on the Tag and tgo to assignments and browse to Azure AD group.

Since its under Roles, I'm assuming it falls under the **roleAssignment** or **roleScopeTag** resource types?

I have thoroughly read all documentation for the REST api and I have also attempted to do this via Microsoft.Graph.Intune modules but still cannot find a suitable cmdlet that will do this. Am I missing something?

Here is the current code I have built following [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-rbac-rolescopetag-assign?view=graph-rest-beta)

**FIRST** let's assume I have the correct tag id and azure ad group object id.

```
$ScopeTagId = 2
$TargetGroupIds = @()
$TargetGroupIds += '687c08f1-e78f-4506-b4a6-dfe35a05d138'

$graphApiVersion = "beta"
$Resource = "deviceManagement/roleScopeTags"

$object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
$object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'assignments' -Value @($TargetGroupIds)
$JSON = $object | ConvertTo-Json

$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/$graphApiVersion/$($Resource)/$ScopeTagId/assign"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $uri -Headers $global:authToken -Body $JSON
```

**No success.** I then thought that since the *create roleScopeTag* API doesn't have an assignment property in the request body, this must be done using the [*update* method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-rbac-rolescopetag-update?view=graph-rest-beta), but that doesn't have it in there either. The only one I read was to use the [*assign action*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-rbac-rolescopetag-assign?view=graph-rest-beta) and in the documentation example it shows the [*roleScopeTagAutoAssignment*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-rbac-rolescopetagautoassignment-create?view=graph-rest-beta) URI, so I went down that rabbit hole:

```
$ScopeTagId = 2
$TargetGroupIds = @()
$TargetGroupIds += '687c08f1-e78f-4506-b4a6-dfe35a05d138'

$graphApiVersion = "beta"
$Resource = "deviceManagement/roleScopeTags"

$AutoTagObject = @()
foreach ($TargetGroupId in $TargetGroupIds) {
    #Build custom object for assignment
    $AssignmentProperties = "" | Select '@odata.type',id,target
    $AssignmentProperties.'@odata.type' = '#microsoft.graph.roleScopeTagAutoAssignment'
    $AssignmentProperties.id = $TargetGroupId

    #Build custom object for target
    $targetProperties = "" | Select "@odata.type",deviceAndAppManagementAssignmentFilterId,deviceAndAppManagementAssignmentFilterType
    $targetProperties."@odata.type" = "microsoft.graph.deviceAndAppManagementAssignmentTarget"
    $targetProperties.deviceAndAppManagementAssignmentFilterId = $TargetGroupId
    $targetProperties.deviceAndAppManagementAssignmentFilterType = 'include'

    #add target object to assignment
    $AssignmentProperties.target = $targetProperties

    $AutoTagObject += $AssignmentProperties

}
#build body object
$object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
$object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'assignments' -Value @($AutoTagObject)
$JSON = $object | ConvertTo-Json

$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/$graphApiVersion/$($Resource)/$ScopeTagId/assign"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $uri -Headers $global:authToken -Body $JSON
```

The error I get back is something like: *"Property target in payload has a value that does not match schema.","innerError":{"date":"2022-01-27T16:28:34","request-id":"75626c4d-f09b-438e-8b0f-0b2928ac23ce","client-request-id":"75626c4d-f09b-438e-8b0f-0b2928ac23ce"* which I assume is the odata.type object i'm calling *"microsoft.graph.deviceAndAppManagementAssignmentTarget"*

There is a **second** post method in the documentations via *roledefinition* URI which seems like an unnecessary step, but I tried that too with no success.

I do not know if any of this is correct. I understand the API calls for others pretty well and I **have** been able to successfully add Tags for Custom Roles and their assignments using graph; I just can't seem to find the right combination of URI and JSON body for scope tags themselves...if it even exists. :(

Any ideas, please share some code snippets if you can. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

I found the correct URI and request body

If can be generated like this:

```
$ScopeTagId = 2
$TargetGroupIds = @()
$TargetGroupIds += '687c08f1-e78f-4506-b4a6-dfe35a05d138'

$graphApiVersion = "beta"
$Resource = "deviceManagement/roleScopeTags"

$AutoTagObject = @()
#TEST $TargetGroupId = $TargetGroupIds[0]
foreach ($TargetGroupId in $TargetGroupIds) {
    #Build custom object for assignment
    $AssignmentProperties = "" | Select id,target
    $AssignmentProperties.id = ($TargetGroupId + '_' + $ScopeTagId)


    #Build custom object for target
    $targetProperties = "" | Select "@odata.type",deviceAndAppManagementAssignmentFilterId,deviceAndAppManagementAssignmentFilterType,groupId
    $targetProperties."@odata.type" = "microsoft.graph.groupAssignmentTarget"
    $targetProperties.deviceAndAppManagementAssignmentFilterId = $null
    $targetProperties.deviceAndAppManagementAssignmentFilterType = 'none'
    $targetProperties.groupId = $TargetGroupId

    #add target object to assignment
    $AssignmentProperties.target = $targetProperties

    $AutoTagObject += $AssignmentProperties

}
#build body object
$object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
$object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'assignments' -Value @($AutoTagObject)
$JSON = $object | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/$graphApiVersion/$($Resource)/$ScopeTagId/assign"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $uri -Headers $global:authToken -Body $JSON -ErrorAction Stop
```

The Json request body would look like this:

```
{
"assignments": [
    {
        "id": "b25c80e3-78cc-4b7c-888e-fc50dcc6b582_2",
        "target": {
            "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.groupAssignmentTarget",
            "deviceAndAppManagementAssignmentFilterId": null,
            "deviceAndAppManagementAssignmentFilterType": "none",
            "groupId": "b25c80e3-78cc-4b7c-888e-fc50dcc6b582"
        }
    }
]
}
```

Nowhere is this documented...